# Spatial analysis to find nearby public transit options given a longitude/latitude and radius?

Tags: python-3.x, gis, geospatial, foursquare, folium

I recently used foursquare's API to get a list of venues nearby a given region, and it looks like it's returned mostly commercial businesses like restaurants, pubs, gyms, and cafes.

I was wondering if it were possible to add "public transit" to the list, for instance, the number of bus stops nearby.

As an example, here's an image of a map I created using folium (in python) and foursquare API to find restaurants in a radius near a long/lat.

[image]

Highlighted in the blue, you can see nearby venues to a longitude/latitude I provided, and also the description of one of these venues in the white box.

Circled in red are what appear to be public transit options, though these are not picked up in my analysis.

I was wondering if there were some API or dataset that I could use to pick up on these bus-stops/train-stops too?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would try OpenStreetMap.

If you are using default base layer in this Folium map, it comes from OpenStreetMaps data too, so you should get exactly the bus stops you see here.